# How to design a simple form in android?

Tags: android

I need to create a simple form in which I give a description like "Name" and give a textbox below it to give the name. But, I am not able to achieve using this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.8"
        android:text="Name *"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

   <EditText
          android:id="@+id/name_edt"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="3" />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.8"
        android:text="Training Types *"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/trainingtypes_edt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check my answer...hope it works for u..if not pls post ur desired image..

Comment: post the screenshot what you get and what you actually want.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post image.

Comment: @A.R. k tell me wat u need exactly.....

Comment: Thank you. But, I have already resolved the issue.

Comment: @A.R. great..u welcome and if my code is helped u pls accept or upvote it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try below code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Field1" 
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Field2" 
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Field3" 
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But I need to display the EditText below "name"

Comment: what do you mean by below name?? it is showing below name, first name textview and below it edittext

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I did not change much. I just correct some codes. Try to find those and enjoy :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Name *"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_edt"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Training Types *"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trainingtypes_edt"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Training types"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.Afieldinc.registeruser.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/PassWord" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SignIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign In" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/SignUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Sign Up"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PassWord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/PassWord"
        android:layout_below="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Password" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

try this one out i hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

try this. when `orientation` is `vertical` u should give `height`  to `0dp`, and when `orientation` is `horizontal` u should give `width` as `0dp` if u r specifying `weight`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.8"
        android:text="Name *"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_edt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.8"
        android:text="Training Types *"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trainingtypes_edt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it working properly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Name *"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_edt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Training Types *"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trainingtypes_edt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps ... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name *" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_edt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Training Types *" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trainingtypes_edt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```